# Why does lseek allow me to set a negative file position?

Tags: c, linux

The man entry says `lseek` should return `-1` if the resulting file offset would be negative for a regular file.

Why does code like this work?

```
int fd;
off_t offset;

fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR);
offset = lseek(fd, -10, SEEK_SET);

printf("%d\n", offset);                // prints -10

if (offset == (off_t) -1)
    perror("seek");                    // error not triggered
```

I feel like I should get `offset=-1` and `errno` set to `EINVAL`.

This also causes the file size to appear extremely large (close to the size of an unsigned int) - seems like an overflow issue.  Why is that?

Comment: Could your file size it reports be UINT32_MAX-1?

Comment: At least on my system `lseek(-10)` returns -1 and "Invalid argument".

Comment: what OS / compiler / stdlib are you using?

Comment: Please post complete, executable examples when possible (to make reproduction easier).

Comment: @zch the irony, of course, is that in this case the presence/absence of the headers impact the result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your "erroneous" behaviour. You must include `unistd.h` to get the proper prototype. With this include, `lseek` behaves as described.

When you miss this include, the compiler passes an *int* `-10` instead of an *off_t* `-10`. This results in your observed behaviour.

*Update:*

The complete list of needed includes is

- [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)

  ```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
  ```
- [`lseek(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html)

  ```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
  ```
- [`printf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html),
  [`perror(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)

  ```
    #include <stdio.h>
  ```

Comment: `gcc -Wall` complains about "implicit declaration of function ‘lseek’"

Comment: `-Wformat` warns about the return value `offset` used in `printf`, not the missing declaration.

Comment: Yet another reason the default should be `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration`. Implicit functions are NOT valid C, are very dangerous, and should not be accepted by the compiler.

Comment: @R.. I won't argue on that.

Comment: I take it that this would also fix the call to `open`?

Comment: @DennisMeng `open` is declared in `fcntl.h`, see [OPEN(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)

Comment: `open` needs `fcntl.h`, but yes. And calling `open` without a declaration is even more dangerous since it's variadic.

Answer (score 5):

> A negative file offset may be valid for some devices in some implementations.

The POSIX.1-1990 standard did not `specifically prohibit lseek() from returning a negative offset`. Therefore, an application was required to clear errno prior to the call and check errno upon return to determine whether a return value of `( off_t)-1` is a negative offset or an indication of an error condition.

The standard developers did not wish to require this action on the part of a conforming application, and chose to require that errno be set to `[EINVAL]` when the resulting file offset would be negative for a regular file, block special file, or directory.

See [lseek](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html)